# Bootstrap countdown timer Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, countdown, countdowntimer

I have the website: http://www.indiespil.dk/aitasi-under-construction-page/Aitasi/image/

I need to change the countdown timer, I am using Bootstrap, CSS and HTML.

The timer is a Jquery timer, this one: https://github.com/rendro/countdown/

I downloaded a HTML template and I have been editing. This single problem really struggles me! The code looks like this:

```
(function () {
  // Countdown
    // To change date, simply edit: var endDate = January 26, 2015 20:39:00";
    $(function() {
      var endDate = "January 26, 2015 20:39:00";
      $('.tk-countdown .row').countdown({
        date: endDate,
        render: function(data) {
          $(this.el).html('<div><div class="days"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + '</span><span>days</span></div><div class="hours"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + '</span><span>hours</span></div></div><div class="tk-countdown-ms"><div class="minutes"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + '</span><span>minutes</span></div><div class="seconds"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + '</span><span>seconds</span></div></div>');
        }
      });
    }); 
}());
```

When I change the Date to February, 28 2015 20:00:00 it simply removes the entire countdown timer from my website. What can I do?

Comment: Could you please past the code into your answer rather than use an image, please?  It would make it a lot easier to read.  Just add a few lines to your answer, paste the code, highlight it, and click the `{}` button in the editor to format it.

Comment: Are you able to open the javascript console and see if an error is being thrown when you make the change?  In chrome you can use command+option+j on mac or ctrl+alt+j on windows.

Comment: Sorry I am not entirely sure what you mean, by the latest reply? What is a Javascript Console? ... god I feel retarded.

Comment: It's alright.  Most modern browsers have a window that you can open that shows errors that are thrown by javascript.  If you open that window when you view your page, it should tell you more or less why the javascipt is not running.

Comment: Okay, give me 2 seconds.

Comment: I get this one:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? scripts.js:1

Comment: I changed the "var endDate = "January 26, 2015 20:39:00";

to

var endDate = "February 26, 2015 20:00:00

Comment: That error is because at the very top of your script file, there is a ? before `jQuery`.  Change `?jQuery` to `jQuery` on line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't try the code myself, I'm willing to bet that the issue is an incorrect date format.  in the original code, it has `January 26, 2015 20:39:00`, but you're trying to use `February, 28 2015 20:00:00`.  See below:

```
January 26, 2015 20:39:00
February, 28 2015 20:00:00
        ^-------------------- this comma is misplaced
```

Change it to `February 28, 2015 20:00:00` and I bet you it'll work.

Edit:

looks like there is also a typo at the top of the file.  It has

```
?jQuery(function($){
```

for line 1.  Remove the `?`

Comment: @EmilFrølund Glad to hear it! Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you, now I only have 1 thing left and my website is perfect. How do I get the buttons (facebook, twitter, linkedin) to work :-D that's a whole new chapter. But I have to wait 90 minutes before I can make a new post :/

Comment: That depends a lot on how the content is served up.  If it's just a simple html file (e.g. index.html) then on lines 144 to 170 you'll notice anchor tags that have `href=""`  You'll want to add the url right in those quotes.  So for instance one might be `<a class="linkedin-icon" href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=1345678">` (of course you would need to go get the right link)

Answer (score 0):

Yea sorry - I am totally new to this forum, so I was not sure how to do it :)

```
// =============================================
//  Countdown
// =============================================

(function () {
  // Countdown
    // To change date, simply edit: var endDate = January 26, 2015 20:39:00";
    $(function() {
      var endDate = "January 26, 2015 20:39:00";
      $('.tk-countdown .row').countdown({
        date: endDate,
        render: function(data) {
          $(this.el).html('<div><div class="days"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + '</span><span>days</span></div><div class="hours"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + '</span><span>hours</span></div></div><div class="tk-countdown-ms"><div class="minutes"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + '</span><span>minutes</span></div><div class="seconds"><span>' + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + '</span><span>seconds</span></div></div>');
        }
      });
    }); 
}());


});
```

Thanks for letting me know ho to do it! :)